# Django form: setting initial value on DateField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following code to set the initial value for a DateField and CharField. CharField's initial value got set properly, but the DateField's initial value is still blank.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dummy = fiscal_year_end = forms.CharField()
    date = forms.DateField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        today = datetime.date.today()
        new_date = datetime.date(year=today.year-1, month=today.month, day=today.day)
        self.fields["date"].initial = new_date
        self.fields["dummy"].initial = 'abc'
```

Comment: where have you defined your Model on the form?

Answer (score 18):

You can set the default value in the same line where you're creating the DateField:

```
date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
```

Or if you want to pass a specific date, you could create a funciton and pass it to the DateField, as follows:

```
def my_date():
    return datetime.date(year=today.year-1, month=today.month, day=today.day)


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #...
    date = forms.DateField(initial=my_date)
    #...
```

In addition, you could review the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial) for more help on this ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this is answering the (not 100% clear) initial question, but I got here so here's my solution.

The HTML `value` attribute of the date field contained the date, but formatted in a way that depended on the language, and was never the expected one. Forcing the date to ISO format did the trick:

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['my_date'] = self.instance.my_date.isoformat()  # Here
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question but it works when you use a simple datetime object. For example.

```
tomorrow = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
send_at_date = forms.DateField(
    required=True,
    initial=tomorrow,
    widget=DateInput(attrs={"type": "date"}),
)
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: How is it different from the other answers? They also recommended the same solution.

Comment: Because it provides a different perspective on the same problem. When you're stuck and searching for answers, perspective in solutions is important since it's the group of perspectives that often provides you with your own solution. So while it may not 'technically' be different, the lingo might appeal to a stuck comrade. Thanks for asking. ✌️

Answer (score 1):

One way I've found for this to work regardless of locale is to define a function that returns the date by forcing the expected format.

```
import datetime
def today_ymd():
    """Return today in format YYYY-MM-DD"""
    return datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then passing the reference of that function to the initial parameter (function name without parentheses).

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_date = forms.DateField(
        initial=today_ymd,
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all proposed solutions, none of them are working. The only thing that works for me is to set the date using JavaScript.

```
{% block js %}
    {{block.super}}
    <script>
        function date_2_string(dt) {
            let day = ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2);
            let month = ("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            let today = dt.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
            return today
        }
        function current_date() {
            let now = new Date();
            return date_2_string(now)
        }
        $("#date").val(current_date());
    </script>
{% endblock js %}
```

Answer (score -1):

just this code worked for my case

set **init** method!

override Form that you want to change attribute

and set initial value in which need to be changed of set with initial value

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AssignedModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['finished_date'] = timezone.now()  # Here
```