# CurrentDate variable not display as Value in input box

Tags: django, widget

I was wondering what's wrong with the form I made.

[image]

It's a Date Input text box where it automatically populates the current date.

Could someone point out what's wrong?

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
currentDate = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")



class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'


class salesForm(forms.Form):

entryDateField = forms.DateField(label="Entry Date", widget=DateInput(attrs={'value': currentDate, 'readonly': 'readonly', 'class':'col-sm-8'}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should use `initial` attribute.

```
from datetime import date


def current_date():
    today = date.today()
    return today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

# in your form class
date = forms.DateField(initial=current_date)
```

Comment: Hello @MojixCoder, Thanks for your input! But it still didn't work. the date input is still unpopulated with the current date.

Comment: Hey, please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881089/django-form-setting-initial-value-on-datefield).

Comment: yeah, actually. It's working if i use your example. but the thing is when i combined the 'initial=current_date' to my existing code. nothing is happening.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my 'widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'col-sm-8'})' code...

Comment: Well don't use it inside your widget, use it on your `DateField`

Comment: and please remove `value` as well.

Comment: Yes, i put the initial=current_date outside the widget. the thing is, I need the widget code. Is there another way to add the current date?

Comment: no in Django forms if you want to add value to your field you should use `initial` attribute.