# How to set default date in SelectDateWidget in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I am using `SelectDateWidget` widget for entering date in the form field. But I want it  to show the current date by default. How can I do that?

**model.py**

```
bdate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

This is giving error. can anyone tell the correct way to do that?

Also, my in template

```
{{ form.bdate }}
```

when I use the above mentioned line in my template it displays like this **--    --   --**
but I want something like this **month   date   year**. how can i do this?

My form is:

```
widgets = {
      'bdate' : SelectDateWidget(),         
      }
```

Answer (score 8):

Using Django 1.3 the following worked for me:

```
join_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(), label='Joining Date', initial=timezone.now())
```

The keyword is `initial` not `default`.

Answer (score 1):

There was similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-default-datetime-now-problem)

Try to use `default=datetime.date.today` or `auto_now_add=True`

Comment: `auto_now_add=True` will have the result of automatically setting the date to now on save, *but* it won't make the actual field display anything by default. If fact, it really only makes sense to use it in conjunction with `editable=False`.