# Set default date with Django SelectDateWidget

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Firstly, this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709116/how-to-set-defult-date-in-selectdatewidget-in-django), however the answer does not work, and is also for Django 1.3. Having done extensive research on similar questions on SO, the Django Docs, and general Googling, I still can't find a working answer. Not really a major detail, but it's annoying both when trying to use the form I'm creating, and because I can't solve it.

When using the SelectDateWidget in a ModelForm, I want to be able to set the default on the widget to today's date.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Article
from django.utils import timezone

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
publish=forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(), initial = timezone.now)
class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = [
    'title',

      ...

    'publish',
    ]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from Blog.models import Category

class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120, unique=True)

      ...

    publish = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

I'm assuming I have some syntax error somewhere, but have had no joy in finding it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @v.s.danilov I don't get an error per se, just the widget never changes from being preset to 01 Jan 2016, no matter how I play around with the Model or ModelForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a subtle difference when setting the the default time for `DateTimeField` and `DateField`.

> DateField.auto_now_add Automatically set the field to now when the
>   object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that
>   the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that
>   you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when
>   creating the object, it will be ignored. If you want to be able to
>   modify this field, set the following instead of auto_now_add=True:
>
> **For DateField: default=date.today - from datetime.date.today()**
>   For DateTimeField: default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now()

So, you'll want to use `date.today` rather than `timezone.now`.