# Timestamp on new object in heroku app is set to heroku's server start time, not actual utcnow time

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I've got an app on heroku that is setting incorrect timestamps for new objects. I can't figure out why for the life of me.

What's happening:

1. I'm submitting a form on the heroku-run website.
2. Django view creates new object and saves
3. models.py has "*ts = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now(utc))*" so it should be saving the utc timestamp at submission (which it does locally), but on heroku it saves the timestamp of when the server started.

Models.py:

```
class NewsArticle(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField(max_length = 2000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    img_path = models.CharField(null = True, max_length = 300)
    ts = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now(utc))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

Views.py:

```
news_article = NewsArticle(...)
news_article.save()

print news_article.ts
print datetime.now(utc)
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Corresponding output in heroku logs (I restarted the Heroku server at 22:00:34 UTC):

```
2013-01-02T22:01:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-01-02 22:00:34.746547+00:00
2013-01-02T22:01:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-01-02 22:01:56.919520+00:00
```

And then again 15 minutes later:

```
2013-01-02T22:15:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-01-02 22:00:34.746547+00:00
2013-01-02T22:15:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-01-02 22:15:46.489815+00:00
```

Clearly something isn't right with the datetime.now(utc) call that's happening in models.py, but I'm not sure why. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: My guess is that it's related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-default-datetime-now-problem - so that each instance is launched isn't hanging around, and you have to explicitly make it get the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely in how you set your default.  The following two sets of code are identical:

```
now_at_import = datetime.now(utc)
MyModel
  ...
  ts = models.DateTimeField(default = now_at_import)

#is exactly the same as
MyModel
  ...
  ts = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now(utc))
```

What you want instead is:

```
def get_utc_now():
  return datetime.now(utc)


MyModel
  ...
  ts = models.DateTimeField(default = get_utc_now)
```

Comment: Ahhh you're right. That fixed it. Thanks a lot. Can't say I would have gotten that anytime soon.