# django admin, None dateField added

Tags: django, django-models

I've got simple model in django.

```
class Period(models.Model):
    date_beg = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=False, editable=True)
    date_end = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=False, editable=True)
```

When I insert data in django admin, it still displays `None` in date field. I have set correct date format of course.

Comment: What did you import? `from datetime import date`? Also, you have to call today as a method not a property. So try `date.today()`

Comment: yes, I imported that. Default value is irrelevant, it works good when I try to edit it(date_today() works the same). But when I save a new data (in django admin) and watch the results the value of date is None.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe can help you: [Django datetime issues (default=datetime.now())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-default-datetime-now-problem)

For DateTimeField, DateField, TimeField, etc

Setting null=True
Okay if you want to be able to set the value to NULL in the database

Setting blank=True
Okay if you want the corresponding form widget to accept empty values, or if you are using auto now or auto now add. If so, you will also want to set null=True.

This is taken from [Django 1.5 book](https://django.2scoops.org/)