# Django default=datetime.now() in models always saves same datetime after uwsgi reset

Tags: python, django, datetime, uwsgi

I have this code in my model:

```
added_time = models.DateTimeField(
    default=datetime.datetime.now()
)
```

After I migrate and restart uwsgi, I get first datetime in MariaDB now, and all next - exactly the same as first after resetting uwsgi.

```
2015-04-19 16:01:46
2015-04-19 16:01:46
2015-04-19 16:01:46
2015-04-19 16:01:46
```

I fixed it by changing code to:

```
added_time = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True
)
```

Though I fixed the problem, I'm not really sure why there even was such behavior?

Comment: I don't know much about Django, but my money is on `default` being evaluated only once, when the class is evaluated. It happens with keyword arguments to functions as well. Try: `def foo(argument=datetime.datetime.now()): print argument` and then test it with a `while` loop or something: `while True: foo()` You'll see that `argument` doesn't change

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django. default=datetime.now() problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-default-datetime-now-problem)

Comment: If you're here because `datetime.now` is not evaluating in your class defaults please see my post here: https://dhariri.com/posts/56f68c45d1befa569505cf0f

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`default=datetime.datetime.now()` is evaluated at parsing/compile time of the model. It is not changed afterwards. To evaluate `now()` at the time of adding/updating an object, you have to use:

`default=datetime.datetime.now`, which sets `now` as the callable. Django will call it at runtime.

Your solution of using `auto_now_add` is of course also correct (yet semantically different -- passing a default will set the value every time the model is saved, whereas `auto_now_add` only does it once, at creation time).

Don't dispair, this is avery [common](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) mistake.

Comment: thank you too, kind sir! you not only saved my day, but showed wonderful site with python gotchas

Comment: In your last paragraph, you linked to a website explaining how the default arguments of a function are mutable and persistent. This is a completely different gotcha then the one that is in play in this question post: in Python, `example` gives the function, whereas `example()` calls the function and gives the return value, unlike, say, Perl, where `example` and `example()` are equivalent, and `&example` is the way to retrieve the reference to the function.

Comment: yes, I agree these are actually different cases. However, it is the same root cause -- the argument is evaluated at compile time, not at runtime as one might assume on first sight.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass `datetime.datetime.now` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` to default. Otherwise, the default value is computed when the model is initialized hence you always get the same value after a restart.

See the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default) for a more thorough explanation.

If using Django's time zones support, remember to use [django.utils.timezone.now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) instead of `datetime.datetime.now`.