# Django datetime default value in migrations

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

I've read some questions about this issue in so, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2771676/5476782) question is **not** giving the correct answer for my case:

I'm adding a created_time field in my already existing models, so no date in the mysql table belonging to the model.

```
class Configs(models.Model):
    ...
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

I apply the migration using `python manage.py makemigrations`

And I get this error:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'creation_date' to
>   collections without a default; we can't do that (the database needs
>   something to populate existing rows). Please select a fix:

I tryed many options:

```
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This one is giving the same error.

How can this migration be achieved, if USE_TZ in settings is set to False?
Btw, is this a bug in Django 1.9.4 `makemigrations` script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) set the current datetime when the instance is created, which never happens during your migration so you are trying to leave `NULL` a non-nullable field.

The solution would be to add a default date to your model, `makemigrations`, then remove the default parameter from the model, `makemigrations` again and finally `migrate`. You can achieve the same adding `null=True` to the field, adding a [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) or [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) to your migration that populates the field, and then remove the `null=true` from the field.

At the end you can merge both migration files (or simple write it yourself) to end with something like:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='configs',
        name='creation_date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True),
    ),
   migrations.RunPython(populate_dates),
   migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='configs',
        name='creation_date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True),
    ),
]
```

I just wrote it so I hope it does not have many typos

Comment: The point is that before setting `null=False` (or remove the argument) you need to populate all the existing rows. You can achieve this by doing what I explained above. Did you do it and still get the same error?

Comment: Thanks, the sentence: `field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)` did solve my problem once previously created_time attributes were removed from the db structure.

Comment: @Evhz: Works for me, too, in Django 3.2. When solved, `auto_now_add=False` **shows** the field in `admin/model/<pk>/change` (open for edit), and the same for `auto_now=False`, while the field is hidden in admin *change* view, when `=True` (not available for edit). This behavior may differ from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add), or I can not read docs precisely?