# Django not storing the exact UTC time in db

Tags: django, postgresql, django-timezone

I have a Django API/PostgreSql project, where i try to store the datetime in UTC format, which later i will convert to a correct timezone in the front end with angular.

My current settings are:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'
```

**I was first using UTC, but for some reason the datetime was stored as +1 hour, so i set the time zone to my servers time zone**

Model:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())
```

But still when i retrieve the inserted record, the time is  -3 minutes late.

While when i use the code bellow, it stores a correct time:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

> Am i missing something in the configuration ? What TIME_ZONE should i
>   use, server location time_zone, or it has to do with the servers time
>   setup ?

Comment: Is your server's time off by 3 minutes?

Comment: `date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())` <= This sets the default date to the time when the module is parsed. You probably wanted `default=timezone.now` (note missing parentheses).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django datetime issues (default=datetime.now())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-datetime-issues-default-datetime-now)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed, i dont know why but when im using:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now()) # note: .now() with parenthesizes
```

The time gets stuck, at the time when the server started up.

The fix use:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now) # without ()
```

Im on Django 1.6.5

Comment: Your answer is in the references duplicate ;-).