# Django - Can't set default DateTimeField value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

When I save form with **empty** `date` and `date_added` fields in **django-admin** site then it saves empty values there. I want to save current time instead. Here's code:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Event(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()

class EventPhoto(models.Model):
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/')
```

Why `default=timezone.localtime` doesn't work?

Comment: try `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: try `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar It doesn't work too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out, that the problem is with **django-admin**. If I'll use code like this:

```
new_event = Event(title="blablah", text="some_text")
new_event.save()
```

then it saves `DateField` properly using `default=timezone.localtime`.
Probably **django-admin** tried to pass empty string to `DateField` instead of not touching it and letting it take default action.

Answer (score 1):

Django `DateField` provides [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) arguments for this:

```
date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: AFAIK I won't be able to change date later if I'll use it - [best comment to answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-datetime-issues-default-datetime-now)

Comment: @Qback yes, since you need default, I suppose you have to remove `null=True, blank=True` in your fields declaration.

Comment: But when I don't use them I'm not able to save form with empty fields in `django-admin`. Also when I tried `CharField` with `blank=True` and `default="sometext"` it worked..

Comment: @Qback if you leave only `blank=True` without `null=True` it should make empty field able. And for empty field `default` will be used.

Comment: It throws **Exception** then. `IntegrityError` `NOT NULL constraint failed: news_event.date`. I guess it doesn't accept data I provide do `DateField`. I'm using `timezone.now` now, and still not working.

Comment: @Qback after that change you need to use makemigrations and migrate, after that it will work

Comment: @Exprator yes, yes, I do it.

Answer (score 0):

`timezone.localtime` is a conversion function, not a value, and that's why it cannot be used.

```
Help on function localtime in module django.utils.timezone:

localtime(value, timezone=None)
    Converts an aware datetime.datetime to local time.

    Local time is defined by the current time zone, unless another time zone
    is specified.
```