# overwriting Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

i need to update the columnvalue of a particular field everytime i create a new entry to the table with some hash value.
i created the model as follows:

```
class ICOExchange(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(default=create_UUID('user '),
                          max_length=100, primary_key=True)


    def set_id(self):
        self.id = create_UUID('user ')
```

where `create_UUID(arg)` is a function that generates a hash value according to some inputs and timestamp.
But while adding datasets through the admin panel it doesnt refresh the id and id remains the same.

Comment: Chaging the `id` is a very strange use case, typically it is better to let the `id` remain *fixed*, at all times. Perhaps you can add an extra column.

Comment: The fact that the value remains fixed, is the expected behavior: since (a) `default` is mean as a way to specify an inital value, and (b) here you set as default the *value* that comes out of the `create_UUID` call, you do *not* call the value very time.

Comment: Shouldnt the id change for each new data entry as it is recalculated again and again?

Comment: well Django already automatically create's an `id` here. If you want to perform hashing of data, you better construct an *extra* column, and furthermore override the `save(..)` method. But even then, you can circumvent updating with for example `Model.objects.filter(foo=bar).update(qux=14)`.

Comment: don't call the method try this `id = models.CharField(default=create_UUID, max_length=100, primary_key=True)`

Answer (score 0):

create_UUID('user ') is called when the python file is loaded (when the server start), then default keep the same value.

A solution is :

```
default=create_UUID
```

but you have no parameter. Maybe with a lambda you can set a parameter ?

Look this question, this is the same but with datetime : [Django datetime issues (default=datetime.now())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-datetime-issues-default-datetime-now)